# How do I display a message or respond towards an invalid input in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, result;
    float b;
    printf("**This is a simple arithmetic calculator.** \n");
    printf("\n Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%i ", a);
    printf("Please enter a floating point number: ");
    scanf("%f", b);

    result = a + b

    printf("Output: ");
    printf("%i + %f = %lf \n", a, b, result);
    printf("%i - %f = %lf \n", a, b, result);
    printf("%i * %f = %lf \n", a, b, result);
}
```

I need to ensure that your program will not crash if the user enters an invalid input.

Comment: how do you propose `result` will be calculated? automatically? :)

Comment: What is the return value of [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)?

Comment: your program has bugs/errors/typos one of them is scanf("%i ", a);

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` is a function that has also got a return value which indicates how many inputs were inserted correctly. 
So you can just do something like:

```
while (scanf("%i ", a) != 1)
{
   printf("wrong input, try again");
}
```

Comment: Good answer. As a side note I would add: The question's title explicitly asks for a standard C pattern to inform about error conditions. So you should print to stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "wrong input, try again\n"); `

Answer (score 0):

use while loop or if  for scanf

```
while(scanf("%i ", a) !=1){
    printf("invalid input.\n");
}
```

and

```
while(scanf("%f", b) !=1){
    printf("invalid input.\n");
}
```